# The date on my Schengen visa application doesn't match my ticket

Tags: schengen-visas

I applied for a Schengen visa with an invitation from a family member. The invitation is from August 10, but the the ticket I gave to the embassy was from August 11. The real ticket I issued 3 days ago is on August 10. Do you know if the embassy is going to give me the visa from August 10 or 11?

Comment: They will from the evidence you provided, and if you asked for 10 August, they will issue for 10 August *in all likelihood*.  Nobody can give you a more exact answer on the information you have given and the question matches the 'post-submission anxiety' category pretty closely.

Comment: No, we don't know that (that's too short for an answer so I am posting it as a comment).